# ThreadPoolExecutor - Specifying Which Thread Handles a Given Task

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool, task

Is there a good way to implement an execution policy that determines which Thread will handle a given task based on some identification scheme? or is this even a good approach?

I have a requirement to process 1-many files, which I will receive in interleaved chunks. as the chunks arrive I want to make a task out of processing that chunk. The catch is that I do no have the luxury of making the processing code thread-safe, so once a thread in the pool has processed a chunk from a file, i need that same thread to process the rest of that file. I don't care if a thread is processing several files at once, but I cannot have more than one thread from a pool processing the same file at once.

the book "Java Concurrency in Practice" states that you can use execution policies to determine "in what thread will a task be executed?", but I do not grasp how.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could write your own `ThreadPoolExecutor` - but in general there's no way of doing this. The whole point of a thread pool is that you just throw work at it, without caring which thread gets which task. It sounds like you'll need to manage the threads yourself in this case, keeping a map of which thread is handling which file.

Do you know when a file has been finished? If not, you're going to potentially have problems with an ever-growing map...

Comment: You could reuse most of the ThreadPoolExecutor code and just add a filter in front of execute() - but I agree that your pattern doesn't really match what ThreadPoolExecutor is intended for.

Comment: Jon's solution would be quite easy to implement.  You should still use  thread pools, but each pool with a single thread (Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) is associated to one file.  When a chunk arrives, you just call map.get(fileName(chunk)).execute(new TaskChunk(chunk)).  If you want to limit the number of threads, you could also associate many filenames to each thread.

Comment: I do know when I have received the last set of bytes for a file... My impression is that decoupling the task submission from execution is ideal and the statement in the book that I cited gave me the impression that the ThreadPoolExecutor did a lot of the work and I'd just need to implement the policy portion; this would also give me more flexibility if I was ever able to make the processing code thread-safe. I originally considered the way toto described and may just take that approach.

Comment: You can decouple the policy by wrapping the map and thread pools in some other object (MyExecutor) and just calling myExecutor.execute(new TaskChunk(chunk));.  You would then also need a  TaskChunk.getFileName() method so that execute() knows which thread to use.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea might be a Thread per file:

```
HashMap<String, MyThreadImplementer> fileToThreadMap...

class MyThreadImplementer implements Runnable {
    int maxNumParts;
    private List<FileChunk> chunkList...
    private List<FileChunk> doneChunks...

    public MyThreadImplementer(int maxNumberOfParts) {
        maxNumParts=maxNumberOfParts;
    }

    public void run() {
        while( doneChunks.size() < maxNumParts ) {
           Thread.sleep(...)
            if ( !chunkList.isEmpty() ) {
                process each chunk in list and mvoe to done chunks
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you'd need to be careful you don't process 1000 files, and thereby create 1000 threads.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you "do no have the luxury of making the processing code thread-safe", but this does not imply that you need to map files to specific threads.  It just means that you can't start processing the next chunk from a file until the last chunk from that file has finished processing.

Taking advantage of java.util.concurrent, you could maintain a `Map<String, LinkedBlockingQueue<FileChunk>>` (assuming filename as key) in the main thread and assign each chunk to the queue for the respective file as chunks come in.  Then have one `Runnable` blocking on each queue.

That way, only one thread at a time would be processing any given file.  And you wouldn't need to directly mess with threads or maintain multiple thread pools.